# Delay on button background color on highlight state in UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uistackview

i'm trying to build a keypad using stackView and dials with button, i implemented it , but **there is an issue when i tap the button's highlight state color is taking time to update some delay to appear.**
 here is the code:

```
for groupView in keypadView.subviews{
        if let stackView = groupView as? UIStackView{
            for btnView in stackView.subviews{
                if let button = btnView as? UIButton{
                    button.setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor.highlightedButton, forState: .highlighted)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there is any delay in stackView , while it's there in scrollview and tableView.

[image]

Comment: Try to do set color, method in : DispatchQueue.main.sync { }